# How to swap two variables between functions at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, server

I am making a 2D multiplayer game, So I need to swap the x and y values of the two players so that they can see each other moving. This is how I did it, any idea how can i swap it at the same time?

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = "192.168.0.137"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

x_value = 0
y_value = 0

x_value_2 = 0
y_value_2 = 0

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client_1(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION1] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_lenght = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_lenght:
            msg_lenght = int(msg_lenght)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_lenght).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            else:
                msg = msg.split(' ')
                global x_value_2
                global y_value_2
                x_value_2 = msg[0]
                y_value_2 = msg[1]
                print(x_value, y_value)
                msg = x_value + " " + y_value
                msg_lenght = len(msg)
                msg_lenght = str(msg_lenght).encode(FORMAT)
                msg_lenght += b' ' * (HEADER - len(msg))
                conn.send(msg_lenght)
                conn.send((msg).encode(FORMAT))
    
    conn.close()

def handle_client_2(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION2] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_lenght = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_lenght:
            msg_lenght = int(msg_lenght)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_lenght).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            else:
                msg = msg.split(' ')
                global x_value
                global y_value
                x_value = msg[0]
                y_value = msg[1]
                print(x_value, y_value)
                msg = x_value_2 + " " + y_value_2
                msg_lenght = len(msg)
                msg_lenght = str(msg_lenght).encode(FORMAT)
                msg_lenght += b' ' * (HEADER - len(msg))
                conn.send(msg_lenght)
                conn.send((msg).encode(FORMAT))
    
    conn.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print(f"[LISTENING] Sever is listening on {SERVER}")
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    conn_2, addr_2 = server.accept()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client_2, args=(conn_2, addr_2))
    handle_client_2(conn_2, addr_2)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=handle_client_1, args=(conn, addr))
    handle_client_1(conn, addr)
    thread2.start()
    thread.start()

print("[STARTING] Starting......")
start()
```

Any idea how can I swap them at the same time? The two variables can be swapped one after the other but that will give a error in my case as the variables don't get swapped fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to exchange them, but the code isn't quite flexible in the way I did it. I hard coded the exchange part.

```
def get_values(conn):
    msg = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
        quit()

    else:
        msg = msg.split(' ')
        x_value = msg[0]
        y_value = msg[1]
        return x_value, y_value


def exchange(conn_1, addr_1, conn_2, addr_2):
    print("[NEW GAME] started....")

    connected = True

    while connected:
        x_value_1, y_value_1, health_1, shoot_1 = get_values(conn_1)
        x_value_2, y_value_2, health_2, shoot_2 = get_values(conn_2)
        
        message_1 = x_value_2 + " " + y_value_2
        message_2 = x_value_1 + " " + y_value_1

        message_1 = message_1.encode(FORMAT)
        message_2 = message_2.encode(FORMAT)

        conn_1.send(message_1)

        conn_2.send(message_2)
```

This is how I did, hope it helps other people.